# how do I make a page only to be accessed through redirection from a stripe checkout session page, in django?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I want a page (view) to be only accessed through redirection from stripe checkout session page, and not accessible in any other way.

Here is the page that I want to only be accessed through redirection from the stripe checkout session page:

```
   def successView(request):
       data = cartData(request)
       cartItems = data['cartItems']

       context = {'cartItems':cartItems}

       return render(request, 'store/success.html', context)
```

Here is the stripe checkout session page that redirects to the page:

```
class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    line_items_list=[]

    for item in items:
        quantity=item['quantity']
        price_stripe=item['product']['stripe-price']
        line_items_list.append(
            {
                'price': price_stripe,
                'quantity': quantity,
                
            }
            )
    
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        shipping_address_collection={'allowed_countries': ['DK']},
        line_items=line_items_list,
        automatic_tax={
            'enabled': True,
        },
        mode="payment",
        success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + 'success/',
        cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + 'kurv/'
    )

    return redirect(checkout_session.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there can be many solutions and you can find them yourself. But to find a solution, you need to understand what your server knows about the visitor redirected from the Stripe checkout page. You can use two parameters to determine if a user has returned to your site after redirecting from the Stripe checkout page:

- URL parameter `session_id` of the `GET` request;
- HTTP header `Referer`.

With these hints, you can turn on your creativity and implement, for example:

- checking if a session with `session_id` [exists](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=python);
- write into `.htaccess` file some allow / deny / redirecting rules based on `Referrer` value.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see if I can find a solution with your given information

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I have solved it now. Took me no longer than 20 minutes. Used Request.session, which is very easy to understand and use

Comment: @YakupÜnsal Do you mind sharing your solution?